# Instance show with Tree data structure

Tags: haskell

I am new at haskell and I want to instance Tree a with the class show.

```
  data Tree a = Null
               |Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

  instance Show (Tree a) where
    show Null = ""
    show Node ((Tree l) (v) (Tree r)) = "|"--I don´t know how i can do this step
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The braces are in the wrong place. Try `show (Node (Tree l) (v) (Tree r)) = ...`

Comment: It gives an error ERROR file:.\Tree.hs:6 - Undefined data constructor "Tree"

Comment: @tomss I commented on that under Abhinav's answer, simply remove the `Tree`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `show` recursively:

```
data Tree a = Null | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where
  show Null = "Null"
  show (Node l v r) = "(" ++ show l ++ " " ++ show v ++ " " ++ show r ++ ")"
```

Comment: Note that it should be `(Node l v r)` in the pattern, `Tree` is the type constructor, not a value constructor.